# Special chars in base64 decoded string

Tags: special-characters, base64, decode

When I decode (using one of the online decoders) a base64 string, the decoded data returns several special chars like sqaure blocks and `"

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is without seeing the base64 string (the encoded one).

Could also be a problem with the online decoder you're using.

Comment: Uh... is this question finished? Or are you still working on it?

Comment: The other half of my question disappeared, probably because of the special char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

base64 encodes binary data to visible characters. If you decode it, the string will be turned back into the binary data, where some of the bytes won't have an ascii/unicode representation and will show as squares. This is normal behaviour. You should decode the data in the program you want to use the data in.